# How to remove margin space from multiple paragraphs simultaneously in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, indentation, whitespace

Sometimes when copypasting from the web, orgmode retains the margin in the text.
Is there a command in Emacs to remove it?
I know of cycle-spacing, but this is slow as it works line by line.
Is there a way to select the whole document and have this margin removed so it's aligned exactly to the left margin of the page?

[image: screenshot:]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cua-set-rectangle-mark` or `delete-indentation`.

If you enbabled `cua-mode`, `cua-set-rectangle-mark` keybinding should be `C-RET`, it selects text inside a rectangle. So you can select the left margin and then delete it.

`delete-indentation` keybinding is `M-^`, it joins the selected lines and fix up whitespace at join. Without selection it joins the line at point.

Also you can use `F3` and `F4`.

`F3`: Start defining a keyboard macro (`kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter`).

`F4`: If a keyboard macro is being defined, end the definition; otherwise, execute the most recent keyboard macro (`kmacro-end-or-call-macro`).

Comment: You can also use `kill-rectangle` (bound to `C-x r k`) without `cua-mode`: mark the top-left corner of the rectangle with `C-<space>`, move to the bottom-right corner and do `C-x r k`.

Answer (score 0):

***Check `org-indent-mode`, and the value of `org-adapt-indentation`***

Surprising leading whitespaces in `org` buffers are usually a result of `org-indent-mode` being ON.  Turn it off.  Also examine the value of `org-adapt-indentation`.

---

***Define a custom `delete-leading-whitespace` as keyboard macro using `query-replace-regexp` or `indent-rigidly`***

The easiest way to achieve what you want is by defining a custom command using keyboard macros

```lisp
(defalias 'my-delete-leading-whitespace-using-query-replace-regexp
   (kmacro "C-M-% ^ [ SPC \\ \\ t C-e * <return> <return> !"))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>") 'my-delete-leading-whitespace-using-query-replace-regexp)
```

```lisp
(defalias 'my-delete-leading-whitespace-using-indent-rigidly
   (kmacro "C-u - 1 0 0 C-x <tab>"))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'my-delete-leading-whitespace-using-indent-rigidly)
```

This is what my `C-h l` looks like after executing `F11`

```
 <f11> ;; my-delete-leading-whitespace-using-query-replace-regexp
 ;; query-replace-regexp
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; move-end-of-line
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; exit-minibuffer
 ;; exit-minibuffer
 C-h l ;; view-lossage
```

and this is what my `C-h l` looks like after executing `F12`

```
 <f11> ;; my-delete-leading-whitespace-using-query-replace-regexp
 ;; query-replace-regexp
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; move-end-of-line
 ;; self-insert-command
 ;; exit-minibuffer
 ;; exit-minibuffer
 C-h l ;; view-lossage
```

In the `query-replace-regexp` version, there is no closing `]` (and you see a `C-e`).  This is because in my `Emacs` settings, inserting a `[' also inserts the closing  pair` ]'.  If your `Emacs` doesn't insert pairs you have to edit the keyboard macro to insert  `]' slightly.

*Exercise to the reader*:   The macro acts on a region, how do you also make it work on the paragraph.  (Hint: Sneak in the keybinding of `mark-paragraph` in the above `elisp`;  Not so difficult right?)

---

***Define you own custom commands (without knowing any `elisp`) using `name-last-kbd-macro` and `insert-kbd-macro`***

This is how you define a `custom-command` using keyboard macros.  First define some useful keybindings

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-k C-N") #'name-last-kbd-macro)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-k C-I") #'insert-kbd-macro)
```

then do what these sequence of commands do

```
 C-x (         ;; kmacro-start-macro
 C-u           ;; universal-argument
 -         ;; negative-argument
 1         ;; digit-argument
 0         ;; digit-argument
 0         ;; digit-argument
 C-x <tab>     ;; indent-rigidly
 C-x )         ;; kmacro-end-macro
 <escape> >    ;; end-of-buffer
 C-x C-k C-S-n ;; name-last-kbd-macro
 c         ;; self-insert-command
 u         ;; self-insert-command
 s         ;; self-insert-command
 t         ;; self-insert-command
 o         ;; self-insert-command
 m         ;; self-insert-command
 -         ;; self-insert-command
 c         ;; self-insert-command
 o         ;; self-insert-command
 m         ;; self-insert-command
 m         ;; self-insert-command
 a         ;; self-insert-command
 n         ;; self-insert-command
 d         ;; self-insert-command
 <return>      ;; exit-minibuffer
 C-x C-k S-TAB ;; insert-kbd-macro
 c         ;; self-insert-command
 u         ;; self-insert-command
 s         ;; self-insert-command
 t         ;; self-insert-command
 o         ;; self-insert-command
 m         ;; self-insert-command
 -         ;; self-insert-command
 c         ;; self-insert-command
 o         ;; self-insert-command
 m         ;; self-insert-command
 m         ;; self-insert-command
 a         ;; self-insert-command
 n         ;; self-insert-command
 d         ;; self-insert-command
 <return>      ;; minibuffer-complete-and-exit
 C-h l         ;; view-lossage
```

and you will end up with something like

```lisp
(defalias 'custom-command
   (kmacro "C-u - 1 0 0 C-x <tab>"))
```

Now you have written your own custom `elisp` using `keyboard macros`.

Bind that `custom-command` to some key

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'custom-command)
```

---